# Taking 1 seconds for each mp3 file and combine it into 1 file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

im using this code to combine all wanted mp3 file into 1 and its working fine, but i need to cut it then combine it

files: a.mp3, b.mp3, c.mp3 -> each of these file got duration of 3 seconds

expected output 1s of a.mp3 + 1s of b.mp3 + 1s of c.mp3

code im using:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i file.txt -c copy full.mp3
```

file.txt:

```
file 'melodies/a.mp3'
file 'melodies/b.mp3'
file 'melodies/c.mp3'
file 'melodies/d.mp3'
file 'melodies/e.mp3'
```

output: full.mp3 the duration is 9 seconds

Comment: It's not clear why Python is tagged here

Comment: yea sorry, i have changed it

Comment: First of all you have to find out how to cut a single file with ffmpeg which is offtopic here.

Comment: Whichever way you do it your requirement is confusing. You seem to have 5 files and you want 1 second from each. That's 5 seconds in total. So how do you get to 9 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation of `concat` demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1) indicates that it supports various directives to auto-cut input streams: `duration`, `inpoint`, & `outpoint`. Follow the example in the doc.